# How to access profile details using IBM Connections API

Tags: profile, ibm-connections

In our IBM Connections system I can access Profile Details in the user interface. The browser sends a GET request that looks like

```
/profiles/html/profileDetails.do?key=22d38016-399e-49ec-b3f6-6707d7a49799&section=contactInformation
```

Is there an API call that delivers the same information like organizational unit, country, city, telephone, ...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/profiles/json/profile.do?userid=44766D83-BAA2-501C-C125-7E62002578C3
/profiles/json/profile.do?email=user@domain.com
```

or

```
/profiles/atom/profile.do?userid=44766D83-BAA2-501C-C125-7E62002578C3
```

In my experience the atom feed misses sometimes data, but json shows everything of a user.